# When I am in profile set ubuntu server 18.04.1 an installation error occured

Tags: boot

When I am in the profile set in ubuntu server 18.04.1  an error occurred. This happened when was step 8/11 of installation. I am using a USB drive to boot ubuntu server 18.04.1 &18.04.2  but it brings me the same problem. When I try to different USB drive still problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar experience with the Ubuntu Server 19.10 (19.10.1) AMD64 on an Intel NUC8i7BEH when trying to install from a bootable USB Flash Drive created with "Startup Disk Creator” on Ubuntu Desktop or with Rufus on Windows.

Originally, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS AMD64 (18.04.03) USB Flash Drive installer created with Windows “Rufus” and Ubuntu “Startup Disk Creator” was not detecting the M.2 SSD or loading/finding PCIe driver, I'm not sure. It would report "Probing for devices to install to failed".

I burnt Ubuntu Server 19.10 (19.10.1) AMD64 to a DVD and it didn't crash during the "Profile setup" stage.
During install, I updated to 19.10.2 and added OpenSSH package, when requested.
After restarting, it booted and I am able to SSH into it with PuTTY with user credentials!

For good measure, I burnt Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (18.04.03) to a DVD and had the same issues as I did with the USB Drive version of Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (18.04.03), so I'm sticking with 19.10.

Interestingly, Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3 AMD64 did install properly via USB created with "Startup Disk Creator” on Ubuntu Desktop. Also, from the non-install "try" option, I was able to install Ubuntu Core (PC Dawson AMD64 m4 20180507-32).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
Before you type your name / username / password etc., CPU goes to 100% and it crashes.

Solved it by changing the download mirror on the step just before the Profile Setup step.

I left the URL like it was (http://some-default-mirror-server-name/ubuntu) but I changed the mirror server name, then it worked.

(List of available mirrors [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors?) -- note I only changed the server name, not the whole URL)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the network adaptor, after removing the network cable the installation went on fine. Please refer to the below discussion for further details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457987/ubuntu-server-installation-stops-at-curtin-command-in-target

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1317543)