# 20.04 USB installation fails

Tags: dual-boot, server, system-installation, 20.04, raid

I have a home server that I want to upgrade (at long last :) from 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. I put ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso on a USB thumb drive and booted from it, and I got as far as "Profile Setup". But then after a few seconds that was replaced with a screen saying that an error had occurred, encouraging me to file a bug report (which I did of course). But how can I capture some diagnostics to post here to help identify the problem? It said something about writing the log to disk, but I don't know where it put it.

FWIW here are some more details. The computer is a Intel i5-2500K in a Gigabyte GA-Z68M-D2H motherboard. My boot disk has a swap partition at /dev/sda1 and the 16.04 partition at /dev/sda3. For 20.04 I used a spare 127G partition at /dev/sda2, asking the installer to format it ext4. There's also a 5-disk software RAID-6 array with one failed disk that I haven't replaced yet (so, state=clean,degraded, active devices=4) that I left unmounted during installation.

By the way I remember it offered to download an updated installer, 20.05.1 maybe. I said okay.

This sounds a lot like [Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: Failed Install (subiquity...install_fail/add_info)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239226/ubuntu-server-20-04-lts-failed-install-subiquity-install-fail-add-info), except that my error screen contains less information. And in their case there was a RAID too... hmm . It also sounds a bit like [When I am in profile set ubuntu server 18.04.1 an installation error occured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162582/when-i-am-in-profile-set-ubuntu-server-18-04-1-an-installation-error-occured), so I tried a couple of mirrors but that didn't change anything.

TIA everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I wasn't able to figure out exactly what was going wrong, but (as a guess) I tried installing on a partition on a new SSD (instead of sda that held the old 16.04 partition), and that worked. I guess there's something about the old volume that made the 20.04 installer fatally confused. Also, this means the RAID array wasn't a problem. I never did figure out if there's a good way to extract the installer logs, but now I don't need to anymore.